# On session_destroy() Insert Into SQL

Tags: php, sql

I am writing code that is meant to insert values into a SQL table if session_destroy() is executed. The reason for this is that I need to store the current session id into a session_count table if the browser is closed, but also destroy the session. I tried various methods, one of which was

```
if (session_destroy() == True) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO session_count (Session_ID) VALUES ($new_session_id)");
}
```

but it didn't help.

Help is truly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [session_set_save_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) to define your custom handler. And you can write your custom destory function.

Also, you can use [SessionHandlerInterface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php) for php>=5.4